# geom_line not showing line

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to plot a line using `geom_line` from the ggplot package. This line should be interactive and is dependent on the selected state and macro variable over a selected time series. While the majority of it seems to run fine, I cannot seem to get `geom_line()` to plot anything.

I have tried grouping the data, as well as using the `as.numeric()` function for the 'year' variable, but nothing seems to work.

Server:

```
server <- function(input, output){


  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

 ggplot(data = filter(c1, state == input$state1), 
        aes_string(x = as.numeric("year"), y = input$macroVar, group = 1)) +
   geom_line() +
   scale_x_continuous(limits = input$years) +
   labs(title = paste(col_alias(input$state1)),
        x = paste("Year"),
        y = paste(col_alias2(input$macroVar))) +
        theme_bw()})
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({

ggplot(data = filter(c1, state == input$state2),  
       aes_string(x = as.numeric("year"), y = input$macroVar, group = 1)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = input$years) +
  labs(title = paste(col_alias(input$state2)),
       x = paste("Year"),
       y = paste(col_alias2(input$macroVar))) +
      theme_bw() })  
}   

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to stack overflow! Straight up, this strikes me as a ggplot question, not an R Shiny question. We ask for minimal reproducible examples. This doesn't look minimal If the issue is that ggplot will not create a line, start by trying to debug that, outside of a Shiny instance. Once you've had a go at that it will be more encouraging for people on here to help you out.

Comment: Furthermore, since we do not have your data `c1`, even without `shiny` this is unreproducible. When we suggest it should be *reproducible*, you have a good start with the code but not the data. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix string and non-string calls in `aes_string`. You do this with `as.numeric("year")`, mixing `as.numeric()` function with a string column name. Check out this reproducible example:

```
# does not work
ggplot(mtcars, aes_string('mpg', as.factor('cyl'))) +
  geom_point()

# works
ggplot(mtcars, aes_string('mpg', 'as.factor(cyl)')) +
  geom_point()
```

So, you could change your code to `'as.numeric(year)'` as a quick fix. I don't much like that either, `aes_string` gets ugly when you start putting commands in quotes. Instead, I'd suggest either (a) solving the problem upstream by converting your `year` column to numeric *before* plotting, or (b) Update your code to modern techniques using. See the **Quasiquotation** section at the `?aes` help page, with examples at the bottom of the help page and more in the linked `dplyr` vignette.

If this doesn't solve your problem or you need additional help, please make a reproducible example and include it in your question.